# How to convert data frame rows iteratively into time series object and apply auto.arima to each row (with gpu, cudf, cuml)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, cudf, cuml

I have the following df:

head(forecastid)

```
           ID 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022
1          C1   420   423   481   421   393   419   415   440
2          C2  1325  1262  1376  1370  1484  1421  1287  1400
3          C3   547   541   547   550   570   576   556   587
4          C4   349   349   375   346   374   379   433   376
5          C5   721   714   758   716   833   735   711   731
6          C6   420   423   481   421   393   419   415   440
```

im using the following code which works with pandas even number of rows is small

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
import warnings

# Suppress warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Read the CSV file
testingR = pd.read_csv("final_dataset.csv")

# Check the structure of the dataset
print(testingR.head())

# Function to fit ARIMA models and generate forecasts
def fit_arima(series):
    # Adjust the ARIMA order based on your data
    order = (1, 0, 1)
    
    model = ARIMA(series, order=order)
    
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
        fit_model = model.fit()
    
    # Generate a one-step-ahead forecast
    forecast_value = fit_model.forecast(steps=1).iloc[0]
    
    # Set negative forecast values to 0
    forecast_value = max(forecast_value, 0)
    
    return forecast_value

# Apply the function to each row of the dataset (excluding the first column)
testingR['Forecast_2023'] = testingR.iloc[:, 1:].apply(fit_arima, axis=1)
testingR['Forecast_2023'] = testingR['Forecast_2023'].astype(int)
# Print or use the modified dataset as needed
testingR.to_csv('2023_predict.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

it works like a charm, but my original dataset is [1393096 rows x 9 columns]> so it never finishes task. I tried to use Cuml and cudf, but there's always error of user define function compilation or cudf doesn't support iterrrows() any help please?

this is code i'm trying

```
import numpy as np
import cudf
from cuml.tsa import ARIMA as cumlARIMA
import cupy as cp

# Read the CSV file using cudf
testingR = cudf.read_csv("final_dataset.csv")

# Check the structure of the dataset
print(testingR.head())

# Function to fit ARIMA models and generate forecasts for each row
def fit_arima(row):
    # Adjust the ARIMA order based on your data
    order = (1, 0, 1)

    # Convert the row to a CuPy array
    row_cupy = cp.array(row.to_array())

    # Initialize cuml ARIMA model
    model = cumlARIMA(order=order)

    # Fit the cuml ARIMA model
    model.fit(row_cupy)

    # Generate a one-step-ahead forecast
    forecast_value = model.forecast(steps=1).to_array()[0]

    # Set negative forecast values to 0
    forecast_value = max(forecast_value, 0)

    return forecast_value

# Apply the function to each row of the dataset (excluding the first column)
forecast_values = testingR.apply(fit_arima, axis=1)

# Add the forecast values to the DataFrame
testingR['Forecast_2023'] = forecast_values.astype(int)

# Print or use the modified dataset as needed
testingR.to_csv('2023_predict.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Please pick one language (R or python) and clarify the expected output

Comment: Language is python, and output should be forecast for 2023, the first code runs with pandas and 1000 rows but when rows are 1393096 it takes too long time, so i want speed up with cudf and cuml

Comment: The cuML library provides an API for `cuml.tsa.ARIMA` (https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuml/stable/api/#cuml.tsa.ARIMA) but be aware that it expects each time series to be in a column rather than a row. Also, note this piece about performance:

> The implementation is designed to give the best performance when using large batches of time series.